# why is this Haskell function slow?

Tags: optimization, haskell

I have a one-line function which is taking up 25% of my execution time, in a way which is really counter-intuitive to me.

The context is an AI for a board game (Blokus), and specifically what we're doing here is trying to determine if it's legal to put a piece in a particular orientation in the neighborhood of a particular board cell. We have already pre-computed a Word64 (placementBitmap) which shows which cells are taken up by the piece in a particular orientation, and more recently we have computed a Word64 (cornerBitmap) which shows which cells are available surrounding this square. So now we compare them:

```
legalAt (TerritoryCorner _ _ cornerBitmap) (Placement _ _ _ placementBitmap) = (placementBitmap .&. cornerBitmap) == placementBitmap
```

I don't understand how a couple of bitwise operations here could take up more time than the process to calculate the cornerBitmap in the first place. Boxing issues? I'm pretty new to Haskell.

The data constructors for both TerritoryCorner and Placement are defined so that the last argument is strict, for whatever that's worth.

The context in which this is used is a list comprehension:

```
[getMyChild corner placement | corner <- myCorners, placement <- myPlacements, legalAt corner placement]
```

I managed to produce the following Core, but I have no idea how to interpret it:

```
GameState.legalAt [InlPrag=INLINE[0]]
  :: Types.TerritoryCorner -> Types.Placement -> GHC.Bool.Bool
[GblId,
 Arity=2,
 Caf=NoCafRefs,
 Str=DmdType U(AAAL)U(UUUL),
 Unf=Unf{Src=InlineStable, TopLvl=True, Arity=2, Value=True,
         ConLike=True, Cheap=True, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=ALWAYS_IF(unsat_ok=True,boring_ok=False)
         Tmpl= \ (w_soat [Occ=Once!] :: Types.TerritoryCorner)
                 (w1_soaA [Occ=Once!] :: Types.Placement) ->
                 case w_soat of _ { Types.TerritoryCorner _ _ _ ww3_soay ->
                 case w1_soaA of _ { Types.Placement _ _ _ ww7_soaF ->
                 __scc {legalAt main:GameState}
                 case {__pkg_ccall ghc-prim hs_and64 GHC.Prim.Word64#
                               -> GHC.Prim.Word64#
                               -> GHC.Prim.State# GHC.Prim.RealWorld
                               -> (# GHC.Prim.State# GHC.Prim.RealWorld, GHC.Prim.Word64# #)}_aHK
                        ww7_soaF ww3_soay GHC.Prim.realWorld#
                 of _ { (# _, ds3_aHQ [Occ=Once] #) ->
                 GHC.IntWord64.eqWord64# ds3_aHQ ww7_soaF
                 }
                 }
                 }}]
GameState.legalAt =
  \ (w_soat :: Types.TerritoryCorner) (w1_soaA :: Types.Placement) ->
    case w_soat
    of _ { Types.TerritoryCorner ww_soav ww1_soaw ww2_soax ww3_soay ->
    case w1_soaA
    of _ { Types.Placement ww4_soaC ww5_soaD ww6_soaE ww7_soaF ->
    __scc {legalAt main:GameState}
    case {__pkg_ccall ghc-prim hs_and64 GHC.Prim.Word64#
                               -> GHC.Prim.Word64#
                               -> GHC.Prim.State# GHC.Prim.RealWorld
                               -> (# GHC.Prim.State# GHC.Prim.RealWorld, GHC.Prim.Word64# #)}_aHK
           ww7_soaF ww3_soay GHC.Prim.realWorld#
    of _ { (# _, ds3_aHQ #) ->
    GHC.IntWord64.eqWord64# ds3_aHQ ww7_soaF
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you on a 32-bit platform? (And the obvious: Compiling with `-O2`?)

Comment: @ehird Yes, (s)he's on a 32-bit platform, and compiled with optimisations, although that might have been `-O1` :)

Comment: @DanielFischer: That'll teach me to post my guesses as comments rather than answers! :)

Comment: @ehird don't guess, read some more core, then you know ;)

Answer (score 4):

You're on a 32-bit platform, so the 64-bit operations are C-calls, that makes them somewhat slower than on 64-bit platforms. However, that shouldn't cost so much, and the core for `legalAt` is as good as one can hope. I think contrary to your belief, the computations of `cornerBitmap` and `placementBitmap` have not been done before and are forced by `legalAt` and by the profiler the cost is attributed to that.

We'd need to see more code and context to find out more.

Comment: I figure I just must be misunderstanding the way in which the function is called, yes. It may be that it is called much more often relative to other things than I originally thought. I figured maybe there was something wrong with this function which would be obvious to someone with better Haskell knowledge, but I guess not. I'll take another look and return later